# cancel association for inhereted STI model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a has_many association set in an STI parent model called User, the model inheriting from User is Group, and I don't want Group to have the the has_many association, is there a way to do that?

Comment: so let's say user has_many projects. when you do "group.projects" what do you want returned? "Project.none" ? because the association cannot be 'canceled'

Comment: I want a NoMethodError returned.
Can I set a condition on the association definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :relations
end

class Group < User
  undef :relations
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't know about 'undef', this is great.